# What should I use instead of LoadWithPartialName()?

Tags: c#, reflection, obsolete

I'm loading an assembly with LoadWithPartialName(), but VS tells me that it's obsolete and to use Load() instead. However, I can't find any convenient overload.

There is a Load(string) with asks for a "full-name" which, if I understood correctly the MSDN docs, includes things like the version number.

There is also a Load (string, Evidence) which accepts a "Display name". The problem is I don't have the slightest idea what the "Display Name" is, as the "Partial Name" I was using with the first function doesn't seem to work.

So, how should it be done?

Comment: Don't bother with "Evidence".  It is also being rendered obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did.  I am loading "Microsoft.AnalysisServices" into PowerShell as my example.

1. Open the GAC folder that has the assembly.  It can be any one of the following:

   - `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32`
   - `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64`
   - `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL`
2. In that folder, open the folder for your assembly.
3. In that folder, you will see another folder that looks like this:

   - `v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91`
4. Break this down into the component parts:

   - v4.0 (I *think* this is the .NET version, but we don't need it here.)
   - 15.0.0.0 (This is the version you're looking for)
   - 89845dcd8080cc91 (This is the public key)
5. Now you can create your assembly string.

   ```
   [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91")
   ```

For .NET assemblies, `Culture` is always `neutral`.